# How to get better control over responsive images break point and alignment with BS3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to control some responsive images placed in a grid.
Unfortunately 2 annoying things occur when the viewport is changed in width:

1. The images which starts out as 4 in a row, quickly becomes 1 in a row even though there is space enough for 2-3 in the viewport.
2. The images are not positioned in center when 1 in a row.

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                    <h2>Image test</h2>

                <hr class="line-color"></hr>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row team-images">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="team-item">
                    <div class="team-text">
                         <h3>John Doe</h3>

                         <h4>COO</h4>

                    </div>
                    <div class="team-image-overlay"></div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="team-item">
                    <div class="team-text">
                         <h3>Moe Joe</h3>

                         <h4>COO</h4>

                    </div>
                    <div class="team-image-overlay"></div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="team-item">
                    <div class="team-text">
                         <h3>Jimbo Joe</h3>

                         <h4>COO</h4>

                    </div>
                    <div class="team-image-overlay"></div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="team-item">
                    <div class="team-text">
                         <h3>Jimmy Joe</h3>

                         <h4>COO</h4>

                    </div>
                    <div class="team-image-overlay"></div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.team-images img {
    max-height:300px;
    width:auto;
}
.team-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.team-text h3 {
    margin-top:5px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: none;
}
.team-text h4 {
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: none;
}
.team-item {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.team-images .team-image-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(41, 128, 185, 0.4);
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .5s;
    transition: all ease .5s;
}
.team-images .team-image-overlay:hover {
    background: rgba(24, 188, 156, 0);
}
```

DEMO:  https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/7189/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your columns, you only specified `col-md-3` which will only trigger during medium to large resolutions.

You can set instead `col-md-3 col-sm-3` or just `col-sm-3` so it will also trigger on smaller res.

Regarding the images not positioned center, you can make it by setting `text-align:center` on their container.

```
.team-images > div {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1L4fgdf5/3/

In response to your comment below, if you don't want to use scaffolding use media queries on css intead.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .team-images .col-md-3 {
      width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/da9b30fn/

Comment: Good solution. One thing that is still annoying is when it reaches the 992px width the images become quite tiny instead of e.g. scaffolding them again so there are 2 in a row instead of 4 extremely small images. How can i control this with Bootstrap?

Comment: `col-md-` is targeting >992 reso. Instead of using `col-md-3` use `col-md-6` so  it will have 2 on each row. Also make sure to set `col-lg-3` so once it get past `1199px` reso it will have 4 images in a row. jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bpvbjegw/1/

Comment: @JavaCake Instead of adding your custom CSS to `.team-images > div` to center images, you could use BS class `text-center` to set `text-align: center;` on images container. See [Alignment classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment).

Comment: @javaCake Nice! Glad to help!